# RegEx - find and replace string

Tags: regex, command-line

i am trying to search my server and find the following in any files.

my regex
`grep -H -r '/\<\?php\spreg_replace\(\"\/\.\*\/e\"\,\.*?\)\;\?\>/gi' /var/www/html/optinsmart/`

i'm looking for this `<?php preg_replace("/.*/e"anything in here);?>` and i want to replace it with nothing or just simply remove it.

it isn't returning any matches at the command line

but when i do `grep '<?php preg_replace("/.*/e"' /var/www/optinsmart/` it returns all of them

is there something wrong in my regex?

**EDIT**

i am trying to find `<?php preg_replace("/.*/e"???);?>` where ??? could be anything.

Comment: _I'm looking for this_. Please be specific what you want to achieve instead of just referring to your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep -F` (fixed string without regex):

```
grep -FHr '<?php preg_replace("/.*/e"' *
```

To delete these line use this sed:

```
sed -i.bak '/<?php preg_replace("\/.*\/e"/d' *
```

Comment: but i need to get the whole PHP code. `<?php preg_replace("/.*/e"???);?>` and the ??? could be anything.. gh32947gh9h 0r a word or numbers or dashes...

Comment: But even that line is also starting with same text `'<?php preg_replace("/.*/e"'` so should it not be fine?

Comment: so with will only go to the end of the line?

Comment: my server got hacked and that code snippet was added to the bottom of all my index.php files. so i want to search for it and remove it from all the files.. Will what you suggested for for that?

Comment: i ended up using `find ./ -name "index.php" | xargs sed -i '/<?php preg_replace("\/.*\/e"/d'`. Thnak you for your help and pointing me in the right direction